# How to get Customized Private DNS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I'd like to use a custom private domain name for EC2 instances within a certain VPC.

**What I did so far:**

Created R53 private zone: example.org
Set DNS resolution=yes and DNS hostnames=yes
Add custom DHCP options set with: domain-name=example.org and domain-name-servers=AmazonProvidedDNS

Every time when I create a new EC2 instance, this instance receives a random aws hostname like ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx and the domain name that is configured in the DHCP options (example.org). This is correct so far.

Unfortunately the private DNS (within the EC2 Console => Descriptions => private DNS) is still something like this: ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.eu-central-1.compute.internal.
How can I say AWS to use our custom domain name (example.org) but sill use R53 for DNS resolution?

Answer (score 0):

It is different services, so you have configure this separately. You can use terraform and create ec2 instance and create route53 record at the same time.